# Rsync tags to give a perfect clone

Tags: rsync, clone

I want to create a perfect clone of a folder, including permissions and ownership.

I'm using command:

```
rsync -a <source> <destination>
```

The sync is missing some of the files that are root access only.
How can I make a perfect clone, with everything?

Comment: Using `sudo rsync ...`? Or are you also concerned about hard links, sparse files, and ACLs?

Comment: You have not mentioned which distribution you are using. So I assumed it is a distribution that brings the `sudo` command and that your user is configured to be allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rsync -aHAX --delete <source> <destination>
```

`sudo` obtains root privileges.

And from `man rsync`:

```
--archive, -a            archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
--hard-links, -H         preserve hard links
--acls, -A               preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
--xattrs, -X             preserve extended attributes
--delete                 delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```